# Puppetteer: How can page.WaitForSelector not throw an error and then page.$ fail?

Tags: puppeteer

Using "puppeteer": "^21.5.0" and configured to put .cache folder in a sub-directory of my working folder

This code snippet sometimes works, but often "fails" with the following console outputs

```
domcontentloaded
get-listing-price.js:29
found "div[data-section-id="stuff"] span.dir-ltr"
get-listing-price.js:37
{amt: '', err: 'selector div[data-section-id="stuff"] span.dir-ltr) failed: null'}
```

edited: This is the entire function

```
async function makeRequest(url, amtSelector) {
    const userAgents = [
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/118.0.2088.76',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    ]
    let amt = '';
    let err = '';

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: 'new' });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    //the don't like scrapers: set a random user agent string
    const uastring = userAgents[Math.floor(Math.random() * userAgents.length)]
    page.setUserAgent(uastring);

    //load our page and wait until it's fully loaded
    try {
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 30000, visible: true });
        console.info('domcontentloaded');
    } catch (e) {
        await browser.close();
        return { amt: '', err: `goto("${url}") failed or timed out` };
    }
    
    try {
        await page.waitForSelector(amtSelector, { timeout: 50000 , visible: true});
        console.info(`found "${amtSelector}"`);
    } catch (e) {
        await browser.close();
        return { amt: '', err: `waitForSelector("${amtSelector}") failed or timed out` };
    }

    const amtSpan = await page.$(amtSelector);  

    if (amtSpan) {
        console.info('amtSpan', amtSpan);
        amt = await amtSpan.evaluate(el => el.textContent);
    }
    else {
        err = `selector ${amtSelector}) failed: ${amtSpan}`;
    }

    await browser.close();
    return { amt: amt, err: err };
}
```

Comment: Please describe your goal/expected result and share a [mcve] including the page you're scraping. Technically, there's the possibility that the page will contain the selector, satisfying the `waitForSelector` predicate, but by the time you try to select it with `$`, it's already been removed from the page. How best to handle it depends on your use case.

Comment: @ggorlen I updated the question with the entire function. The goal is to find the contents of a specifc node with a selector, which I've tested in the browser. Let's assume that the dom element is not being removed

Comment: How are you calling the function? Which page is it running on and what are you trying to accomplish on that page exactly (show the precise expected output--there's often a [totally different way to get it than you assume](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676))? I need to be able to run the code in order to reproduce the behavior and fix the problem, or provide a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen is there a way to wait for and return the results of the selector at the same time? I just heard of puppeteer hours before writing this script, so looking for suggestions

Comment: Yes, you can use [`const el = await page.waitForSelector(...)`](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#not-using-the-return-value-of-waitforselector-and-waitforxpath), but that element handle  can go stale the next time you try to `evaluate()` it, so this probably won't solve the problem. There's also a new [locator API](https://pptr.dev/guides/locators/) with auto-waiting. But it sounds like you may need a bespoke `evaluate()` with a tight polling mutation observer to make sure you get it synchronously. Oftentimes, though, you can get the data more reliably from an API response.

Comment: @ggorlen the locator api works. add an answer if you want the credit

Comment: @ggorlen actually it still does not work. I added taking a screenshot after the call to page.locator. when I comment the screenshot out it fails to find the data I want

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, but like I said, I'm guessing your problem and it's extremely hard to help without a complete, runnable [mcve]. Every page is unique and there are many factors that are hard to anticipate without being able to run the code and see the page.